# Simple stopwatch program with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've self-taught myself Python and have recently started learning tkinter. I made a simple stopwatch program and I wanted to know if the code is clean and written in a way that the code works efficiently. I would highly appreciate any suggestions on how to improve my code! Thank you!

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

numberOfSeconds = 0

def counting():
    global numberOfSeconds
    global stopCounting

    if stopCounting == False:
        numberOfSeconds += 1
        seconds.config(text=str(numberOfSeconds))
        seconds.after(1000, counting)
    elif stopCounting == True:
        stopCounting = False
        numberOfSeconds = 0
        seconds.config(text=str(numberOfSeconds))


def start():
    global stopCounting
    stopCounting = False
    stopButton.config(state=NORMAL)
    seconds.after(1000, counting)

def stop():
    global stopCounting
    stopButton.config(state=DISABLED)
    stopCounting = True


seconds = Label(text=str(numberOfSeconds))
startButton = Button(text="Start", command=start)
stopButton = Button(text="Stop", command=stop, state=DISABLED)

seconds.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
startButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
stopButton.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Globals

Generally speaking it's not a good idea to use globals like this. It harms re-entrance. What if you want to support two stopwatches at once, either in one UI or as a web server? Having globals like this will prevent that.

It also harms testability. It is more difficult to test methods that rely on global state than it is to test methods that are self-contained, having state passed to them either in an object context (`self`) or as method parameters.

One way to get around this is make a class with attributes `number_of_seconds` and `is_counting` (which I find would be more intuitive than `stop_counting`).

### Booleans

This block:

```
if stopCounting == False:
    numberOfSeconds += 1
    seconds.config(text=str(numberOfSeconds))
    seconds.after(1000, counting)
elif stopCounting == True:
    stopCounting = False
    numberOfSeconds = 0
    seconds.config(text=str(numberOfSeconds))
```

is more easily expressed as

```
if stopCounting:
    stopCounting = False
    numberOfSeconds = 0
    seconds.config(text=str(numberOfSeconds))
else:
    numberOfSeconds += 1
    seconds.config(text=str(numberOfSeconds))
    seconds.after(1000, counting)
```

### Variable names

They should be lower_snake_case, i.e. `start_button`.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I don't really understand why I can't be using globals that way, is there any chance you could explain it to me a little bit more?

Comment: I've added a little more explanatory text.

Comment: It's not that you _can't_ do it (you already are); it's that it makes your life more difficult when you have non-trivial application development to do.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you so much for your help!